# jquery validation and blur action

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have this application that uses jquery validation. (Been stopped from using Data Annotations :()

On submit and blur, i want to check for a duplicate value. Since this is my first time encounter with jquery validation (other than data annotation), i am not sure what is the best way here. There is a remote call in action here as well. I am thinking about some thing like following.  Is this the correct way to do it?

```
$("#" + enums.RegisterUsername).rules("add", {
            onkeyup: false,
            **onfocusout/onblur: true, ?????????**
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
            alphanumericwithbasicpunc: true,
            remote: SignUp.DuplicateUserIdCheckUrl,
            messages: {
                required: "<span style='color:red'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Required</span>",
                minlength: "<span style='color:red'>User name must be at least 6 characters in length.</span>",
                alphanumericwithbasicpunc: "<span style='color:red'>User name cannot contain the following characters: &,\, /, #, <, or >.</span>",
                remote: "<span style='color:red'>User name already taken by another user.</span>"
            }
        });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **absolutely cannot** put any of the `.validate()` method options inside of the `.rules()` method.  Only rules (and `messages`) can go inside of this.

```
$("#" + enums.RegisterUsername).rules("add", {
      required: true,
      minlength: 6,
      alphanumericwithbasicpunc: true,
      remote: SignUp.DuplicateUserIdCheckUrl,
      messages: {
          required: "<span style='color:red'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Required</span>",
          minlength: "<span style='color:red'>User name must be at least 6 characters in length.</span>",
          alphanumericwithbasicpunc: "<span style='color:red'>User name cannot contain the following characters: &,\, /, #, <, or >.</span>",
          remote: "<span style='color:red'>User name already taken by another user.</span>"
      }
});
```

---

Also, in every case, `onfocusout` can never be set to `true`.  Validation on blur is already the default behavior so setting this option to `true` can break the plugin.  It can only be set to `false` if you want to disable it, or set to a function to over-ride it.  If you want validation to occur on blur, the `onfocusout` option needs to be left out of `.validate()`.

See the documentation:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Answer (score 0):

I have commented and tested the following. It is working on blur.

```
$("#" + enums.RegisterUsername).rules("add", {
            //onkeyup: false,
            //onfocusout: true,
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
            alphanumericwithbasicpunc: true,
            remote: enums.DuplicateUserIdCheckUrl,
            messages: {
                required: "<span style='color:red'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Required</span>",
                minlength: "<span style='color:red'>&nbsp;&nbsp;User name must be at least 6 characters in length.</span>",
                alphanumericwithbasicpunc: "<span style='color:red'>&nbsp;&nbsp;User name cannot contain the following characters: &,\, /, #, <, or >.</span>",
                remote: "<span style='color:red'>&nbsp;&nbsp;User name already taken by another user.</span>"
            }
        });
```